# jqGrid client side data disappears when clicking on the sort columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid where if I click on the headers to sort, all of my grid data disappears and I don't know why it's happening. Here's a [sample page](http://www.clarkzoo.org/sandbox/jqgrid-empties/repro.htm) I cooked up that repro's the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Disappearing Sort Repro</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="js/jQuery/plugins/jqGrid4/ui.jqgrid.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <table id="ooTruckGrid">
    </table>
    <div id="ooTruckPager">
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/plugins/jqGrid4/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/plugins/jqGrid4/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        _truckList = [];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ooTruckGrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "clientSide",
                colNames: ['id', 'VIN', 'Plate', 'Make', 'Model', 'Year', 'RFID #', 'Description'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true, sorttype: "int" },
                    { name: 'vin', index: 'vin', width: 120, sorttype: "text" },
                    { name: 'plate', index: 'plate', width: 75, sorttype: "text" },
                    { name: 'make', index: 'make', width: 80, sorttype: "text" },
                    { name: 'model', index: 'model', width: 80, sorttype: "text" },
                    { name: 'year', index: 'year', width: 40, sorttype: "int" },
                    { name: 'rfidNo', index: 'rfidNo', width: 50, sorttype: "text" },
                    { name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 100, sortable: false }
                ],
                datatype: 'local',
                hidegrid: false,
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                loadonce: true,
                multiselect: true,
                pgbuttons: false,
                pginput: false,
                rowNum: '',
                pager: '#ooTruckPager',
                sortable: false,
                viewrecords: true
            });

            // Add truck         
            addTruckData(-1, 0, "11111111111111111", "Make 1", "Model 1-1", "2009", "US", "WA", "1D1D1D", "", "Test truck 1");
            addTruckData(-1, 0, "22222222222222222", "Make 2", "Model 2-1", "2010", "US", "WA", "2A2A2A", "11111", "Test truck 2");
            addTruckData(-1, 0, "33333333333333333", "Make 2", "Model 2-2", "2011", "US", "WA", "3B3B3B", "", "Test truck 3");
            addTruckData(-1, 0, "44444444444444444", "Make 1", "Model 1-2", "2006", "US", "WA", "4C4C4C", "22222", "Test truck 4");
            addTruckData(-1, 0, "55555555555555555", "Make 3", "Model 3-1", "2003", "US", "WA", "5E5E5E", "", "Test truck 5");
        });

        function addTruckData(rowId, id, vin, make, model, year, country, state,
            plate, rfid, description) {

            var rowId = -1;
            var method = '';

            var truck = new truckData(-1, // rowId 
            id, vin, make, model, year, country,
            state, plate, rfid, description);

            if (_truckList.length > 0) {
                for (var xx = 0; xx < _truckList.length; xx++) {
                    if (_truckList[xx].vin == vin) {
                        // The vin is already in the list, update it.
                        rowId = _truckList[xx].rowId;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (rowId == -1 && _truckList.length == 0) {
                _truckList = [truck];
                rowId = 0;
                method = 'addRowData';
            }
            else if (rowId == -1) {
                rowId = _truckList.length;
                _truckList.push(truck);
                method = 'addRowData';
            }
            else {
                _truckList[rowId] = truck;
                method = 'setRowData';
            }

            truck.rowId = rowId;
            result = $('#ooTruckGrid').jqGrid(method, rowId, truck.toJqGridData());
        }

        function truckData(rowId, truckId, vin, make, model, year, country, state, plateNum, description, rfid, truckType) {
            return {
                rowId: rowId,
                id: truckId,
                vin: $.trim(vin),
                make: make,
                model: model,
                year: year,
                plateCountry: country,
                plateState: state,
                plateNumber: $.trim(plateNum),
                description: $.trim(description),
                rfid: $.trim(rfid),
                truckType: truckType,
                toJqGridData: function () {
                    return { "id": this.id, 'action': '', 'vin': this.vin,
                        'plate': this.plateCountry + '-' + this.plateState + '-' +
                        this.plateNumber, 'make': this.make, 'model': this.model,
                        'year': this.year, 'rfidNo': this.rfid,
                        'description': this.description
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you go to that link, and then click on one of the headers, all of the data vanishes rather than sorting the grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error, which produce disappearing of data on the column sorting, is the option `rowNum: ''`. If you don't need paging of data you should set some larger enough value for `rowNum` like `rowNum: 10000`. Such change will solve your main problem.

Your code have many other small errors or bad written parts which I want to mention:

- You test page don't includes `jquery-ui.css` which is *really important*. On the other side you includes `jquery-ui.js` which is not needed for jqGrid. You should include it only if you use some jQuery UI functionality.
- The `addTruckData` function contain `rowId` parameter, but you define local variable with the same name and assign the value `var rowId = -1` later in the code. It's wrong of course.
- You should include `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the page header.
- You should remove deprecated `language="javascript"` attribute of `<script>`.
- If you want have correct XHTML 1.0 Transitional page you should include an empty cell `<tr><td/></tr>` inside the `<table>` element. The empty cell will removed during jqGrid initialization.
- You use `<` and `&` characters in the JavaScript code. So to have correct XHTML code you should modify the code or just include the line `//<![CDATA[` at the beginning of the script and the line `//]]>` at it's end.
- You should follow JavaScript standards for classes and remove function `truckData` to `TruckData`.
- You should use the less global variable and global functions as possible. For example functions `TruckData` and `addTruckData` like the variable `_truckList` (better `truckList`) can be moved inside of `$(document).ready(function () {/*here*/});`
- You should define variables before you use there. For example you use `result` without the definition. In the case `result` will be interpret as global variable and will be add as the property to the `windows` object.
- You use `datatype: "clientSide"` and `datatype: 'local'` in the same grid. You should remove `datatype: "clientSide"`.
- You should remove `loadonce: true` because in case of `datatype: 'local'` it has no sense and will be ignored.
- You should remove properties of [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) which are default like `sorttype: "text"` and remove [jqGrid options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) which are also default like `sortable: false`. On the other side you can consider to include `height: 'auto'` parameter.
- I recommend you to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to improve quality of your JavaScript code and use [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to verify HTML markup.

I modified your page once to show how above changes could be done. The demo [here](http://file://storage-5/public/Documents/Oleg/TEMA/1.0/VerticalHeaders/amber2.htm) has not JSLint or W3 validator errors.

Answer (score -1):

add the following line in jqgrid creation scope:

`rowNum: 9007199254740992`

this sets the maximum capacity for rows within jqgrid